# Which agent level is applied to input? (how does inheritance in jenkins look like?)

Tags: jenkins, inheritance, agent

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('stage1') {
      agent any
      input {
        message "What is your first name?"
      }
      steps {
        echo "Test Stage1"
      }
    }
    stage('stage2'){
      steps{
        echo 'Test Stage2'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. In the documentaion of jenkins: (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

> agent none
>
> When applied at the top-level of the pipeline block no global agent will be allocated for the entire Pipeline run and each stage section will need to contain its own agent section.

- In the `stage2` I have not defined agent for it. But when I built the pipeline, the echo command was still normally executed.

2. in this jenkinsfile `agent none` is the top level agent and `agent any` is the stage agent for `stage1`.

   In the documentation of jenkins for input:

> The stage will pause after any options have been applied, and before entering the agent block for that stage or evaluating the when condition of the stage

- Does that mean, that input is a special element, so only the top level agent is applied to input independent of which agent we have in the stage level, in which input in defined?

3. 

- Is this kind of inheritance a feature of Jenkins or groovy scripting?

Answer (score 0):

`echo` command just print to console, it doesn't care about agents,

all commands/groovy scripts executed on server side(on jenkins instance)

like in your example command `echo ""`, but if you use something which requires workspace you will get error

```
ERROR: Attempted to execute a step that requires a node context while ‘agent none’ was specified. Be sure to specify your own ‘node { ... }’ blocks when using ‘agent none’.
```

only specific commands executed on agent side, like `sh` block
which will create sh script on agent via jnlp protocol(or ssh or anything else depends on what you use for connection) and will execute this script on remote from jenkins

input - pauses Pipeline execution to wait for approval, which could be either automated or manual, they take some time by default. At the same time, the agent acquires and locks the workspace and heavyweight Jenkins executor. Hence, it is always good to create your inputs outside your agent within a stage.

we have 2+ cases

1. **correct** and input will not lock agent

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('stage1') {
      steps {
        input "What is your first name?"
      }
    }
    stage('stage2') {
      agent any
      steps {
        input "What is your first name?"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. **wrong** input executed on "agent none" but the stage still will lock top level agent (agent any)

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('stage1') {
      agent none
      steps {
        input "What is your first name?"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. **correct** use nested stages, input will use top lvl agent none
   as nested stages agent already executed and removed

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('top stage for nested stages') {
      agent any
      stages {
        stage("nested stage1") {
          agent any
            steps {
              echo "hello"
            }
        }
        stage("nested stage2") {
          agent any
            steps {
              echo "hello"
            }
        }
      }
    }
    stage("top stage with input") {
      steps {
        input "What is your first name?"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I understand correctly, there's just a number of commands that don't require an agent at all and will never be executed on an agent, no matter if I assigned one or not.
For input, is there a common pattern to make sure it's always executed outside the agent? Should I always use 'agent none' and then only assign 'agent any' inside the stage after getting the input, or... ?

Comment: updated answer^